# Getting a stack backtrace from node.js on timout?

Tags: node.js, express, promise

I am using node.js with domains and `cluster` to catch unexpected exceptions (programmer bugs) then restart gracefully.  However we occasionally have programmers failing to add the final `.catch().finally()` to make sure that their code actually returns.

I can easily add a timeout that will throw an exception after a pre-specified time to make sure that these bad requests will not live forever.  But what I'd like to do is to have the timeout pull information out of the domain to explain what had happened in the request so that we can have a log/notification/whatever that starts with a good indication of where the programmer bug was.

Is there any reasonable way to do that?

In case it matters, we are using `express` as a framework, `express-domain-middleware` to get domains/restart logic, and promises for async logic.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need domains for this. If you use a promise library (like bluebird, or when, or even Q) or a recent version of Node (Namely, io.js) you don't have to remember using `.catch` on all chains and use the dedicated events:

```
 process.on("unhandledRejection", function(e, reason){
      // promise was rejected, even if no `catch` or `finally` attached
      // restart the process
 });
```

Note that domains are deprecated and will likely be removed in a future version of NodeJS, if you're using promises you already have catch safety so there's that.